# Excel VBA formula name manager to automatically update source data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use VBA to set name ranges to reference in source data.

When data are added, the XY Scatter chart these data are plotted on should automatically update (e.g. if I entered 7 at "A8", 1 at "B8", and 9 at "C8", data points at (7,1) and (7,9) would immediately populate on the chart).

There is only one chart and one sheet in the workbook.

[image]

When entering `='Sheet1!Session`, I receive an error that there's a problem with one or more of the formulas used. I receive the same error when entering `='Sheeet1!Measure1'` and `='Sheet1!Measure2'` for each respective y value.

In another workbook, I manually added the names in Name Manager and successfully edited Series' X and Y values.

[image]

I've circled the code used to generate series' names. When I go into name manager, all names show up and are in the scope "Sheet1"

I've tried replacing `wsData` with `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)` to no avail.

Any thoughts?

Comment: add an `=` after the first quote: `...= "=OFFSET..."`

Comment: That did the trick. I recorded a macro for changing the series values, but get an "object variable or with block variable not set 
 `ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "==Sheet1!Session"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "==Sheet1!Measure1"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).XValues = "==Sheet1!Session"
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Values = "==Sheet1!Measure2"`